# How do I get outputs for multiple modules?

Tags: terraform

I have a module I call multiple times in a single tf file. One of the things it does is create an S3 bucket. I have this defined in its output:

```
output "mybucket" {
  value = "${aws_s3_bucket.mybucket.id}"
}
```

In order to view this output though, because I'm using modules, is scope to the specific module which means doing this:

```
terraform output -module=module1 mybucket
```

Which means if I just want a list of ALL the buckets created via the tf file I have to loop over them programmatic. Sadly wildcards do not work:

```
terraform output -module=* mybucket
```

So now, how do I do this? I could loop over all the modules and call output multiple times but I can't find a terraform command that lists all the modules currently in use.

With state list I get the modules names but in a format I have to parse:

```
terraform state list aws_s3_bucket.mybucket

module.module1.aws_s3_bucket.mybucket
module.module2.aws_s3_bucket.mybucket
```

Is there a way to query state and retrieve all the buckets that were created OR a way to view outputs of all modules?

---

Edit: So it seems I can output a list from the tf file that calls the modules. The tf file collects the output of multiple module calls into a list:

```
module "mod1" {..do stuff, create s3 bucket, output{mybucket} ...}
module "mod2" {..do stuff, create s3 bucket, output{mybucket} ...}
module "mod3" {..do stuff, create s3 bucket, output{mybucket} ...}

output "my-buckets" {
  value = ["${module.mod1.mybucket}","${module.mod2.mybucket}"]
}
```

The disappointing thing though is I have to manual enter each modules by name. The splat operator didn't work here to expand the modules- am I using it wrong?:

```
output "my-buckets" {
  value = ["${module.*.mybucket}"]
}
```

The error I get is:

```
* output 'my-buckets': unknown module referenced: *
    output 'my-buckets': undefined module referenced *
```

Comment: The splat operator is only usable when you have a `count` attribute for a resource (note that modules still don't support `count`) as it looks at the list of resources that are in use. Each module is completely separate from each other so you can't use that here. It might be worth trying to explain at a higher level what you're trying to achieve here because there isn't a better option than the ones you've already explored.

Answer (score 0):

Also following up with @ydaetskcoR's answer, the splat notation for your case would look somewhat like:

```
output "output-s3-buckets" {
  value       = "${aws_s3_bucket.mybuckets.*.id}"
  description = "List of buckets created"
}
```

Which can be read at the module declaration level as

```
list_of_buckets = ["${modules.s3_module.output-s3-buckets}"]
```